# Prove that $A$ is similar to $A^n$ based on A's Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A =
>  \begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0&3\\-2&-6&0&13\\0&-3&1&3\\-1&-4&0&8\end{bmatrix}$,
>   Prove that $A$ is similar to $A^n$ for each $n>0$.

I found that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(t-1)^4$, and the minimal polynomial is $(t-1)^3$. And the Jordan form of $A$ is \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I guess the key to solve this is to use the fact that two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same Jordan form.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After computing the Jordan form you only have to check that all powers of $$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ are similiar to each other.

Note that $M=I+N$ where $N^3=0$, so $$M^n = I+nN+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}N^2.$$

We obtain $(M^n-I)^2=n^2N^2 \neq 0$, in particular the minimal polynomial of $M^n$ is $(t-1)^3$, i.e. the Jordan form of $M^n$ is precisely $M$.

Comment: Can we generalize the statement "the Jordan form of $M^n$ is precisely $M$" for   Jordan block $M$ of any dimension ?

Comment: If the eigenvalue of the block is $1$, this should be true for all dimensions.

Comment: but eigenvalue of Jordan block can only be 1 as it is upper triangular matrix... ??

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ **is** a Jordan block with eigenvalue $2$.

Comment: I see, I was suggested by the example. So for eigenvalue 2 we have no similarity..

Comment: Of course not, because the eigenvalues change when taking powers.

Comment: so I suppose we can generalize the statement as follows the Jordan form of $M^n$ has the same superdiagonal  as  Jordan block $M$ ..

Comment: No we cannot. It is clearly false for nilpotent blocks.

Comment: But true for not nilpotent at least?

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: This new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356182/superdiagonal-for-the-jordan-power-of-a-jordan-block