# How do we study sequences whose representative matrix is not diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

As I have learnt when I studied linear algebra, a common way of studying sequences defined by linear recurrences is to represent them using a matrix, then diagonalizing that matrix. For example, the Fibonacci sequence given by $x_1=1$, $x_2=1$, then  $x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$ can be written as
$$\mathbf x_n = \begin{bmatrix}x_n\\x_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{n-1}\\x_{n-2}\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{Ax}_{n-1}.$$
Hence we obtain $\mathbf x_n=\mathbf A^n\mathbf x_1$, then everything else proceeds as usual. We compute the RHS by diagonalizing $\mathbf A$ as $\mathbf{\Sigma\Lambda\Sigma}^{-1}$, then $\mathbf A^n=\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf\Lambda^n\mathbf\Sigma^{-1}$. This is all well and good, and works in the vast majority of cases, but there are sequences whose corresponding matrices cannot be diagonalized; i.e. have repeated eigenvalues. In the $2\times 2$ case I think this is only possible when the $x_{n-1}$ term has coefficient $0$, but what about higher dimensions? What do we do then? Is there some sort of general algorithm still, or do we need to play it by ear?

Comment: Do you know about the Jordan normal form? If so, the question boils down to taking the $n$-th power of a Jordan block (because clearly, taking the $n$-th power of a matrix in Jordan normal form reduces to taking the $n$-th powers of all its Jordan blocks). This has been done, e.g., at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356182/superdiagonal-for-the-jordan-form-of-a-jordan-block-power .

Comment: @darijgrinberg Interesting. I don't know about that at the moment, but I'll go read up on it. Thanks for the link.